# How to add events to Ribbon Buttons

Tags: 2013, javascript, ribbon, events

I want to add custom actions to my save or check-in buttons when a page is in edit mode.

The IDs from the buttons I want to add events:

```
Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.SaveEdit.Menu.SaveEdit.SaveAndStop-Menu16
Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.SaveEdit.Menu.SaveEdit.Save-Menu16
Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.SaveEdit-SelectedItem
Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.Checkout-SelectedItem
Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.Checkout.Menu.Checkout.Checkin-Menu16
ctl00_PageStateActionButton
```

The only button event that gets fired is the `ctl00_PageStateActionButton`
 button.
All other ribbon buttons are not working.

Tried following code:

```
$('#id').on("click", function(e){});
$('body').on("click", "#id", function(e){});
$('body').delegate("#id", "click", function(e){});
```

Also tried the IDs with "\" and without before each "."
But nothing worked.

Comment: How are you presently trying to add this?

Comment: With jquery as I posted. But I beleive it is not possible that easy, because Sharepoint is always overwriting my event registration

Comment: I meant what method are you using to add this jQuery to the site? Where are you adding this? Via Visual Studio/solution, master page, web part on the page or SP Designer?

Comment: Just on the page... Used executeFunc callback after loading sp.js and also tried the add_pageLoaded callback to make sure everything is ready. But it is not working.

Comment: Are you just putting this in a script editor webpart?

Comment: Yes, or in a CEWP.

Comment: If you need to run javascript and it can't be done with other methods, you don't have a great solution. You can try and wrestle with loading your script on page [load or ready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready), but that's got a lot of flaws (may not work 100% of the time)
Ideally, you'd be doing this with either InfoPath (which can allow you to tailor behaviors to the submit button) or with custom actions you'd set up through SharePoint Designer (Designer > pick your list > Custom Action > Edit Form). Neither option will allow JavaScript.

Comment: Editing SP.Ribbon.JS is possible, but requires a lot of access and it is hard to target to one page, so you should want the extra action on a lot of pages.